# C inline functions

Tags: c, linker-errors, inline-functions

As far as i know, `inline` functions in C work pretty the same way as in C++ when used in single translation unit and there's no need to dive into `extern inline` difficulties in such a case. However, the following program including three files seems not to compile in C and I am struggling to figure out why.

#### f.h

```
int f();
inline int g();
```

#### f.c

```
#include "f.h"

inline int g() {
    return 5;
}

int f() {
    return 3 + g();
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include "f.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", f());
    return 0;
}
```

### The linker

tells that there is an *undefined reference to `g`*. However, as `g` is used only in **f.c** file, I can not define where the problem lies exactly.

Comment: You need `extern inline int g();` in one translation unit, in ISO C

Comment: It would help to show your build command, e.g. as GNU C behaves differently to ISO C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.4 Function speciﬁers)

> 7,,,For a function with external linkage, the following restrictions
>   apply: **If a function is declared with an inline function speciﬁer,
>   then it shall also be deﬁned in the same translation unit**

In your project the function `g` is declared in the translation unit with main.